# How to use the DecimalFormat pattern properly

Tags: java, localization, decimalformat

I have checked this [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) and it says that this is the pattern syntax:

pattern    := subpattern{;subpattern} //where the subpattern between curly braces is for negative numbers;

So I tried the following code, but when I try to format a negative number I actually get back a positive number formatted with the first subpattern.

```
   NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("us-US-u-ca-buddhist"));
        DecimalFormat dcfCasted = (DecimalFormat)nf;
        dcfCasted.applyPattern("$000,000.000;000.000");
        System.out.println(dcfCasted.format(-200000.100));
```

I know us-US it's the standard, just wanted to see how it works.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give the expected output and actual output from this snippet of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the definition of [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) ,

> the positive subpattern prefixed with the localized minus sign ('-' in
>   most locales) is used as the negative subpattern.

So make you code like this:

```
dcfCasted.applyPattern("$000,000.000;-000.000");
```